# Soapui maven plugin can not parse XmlHolder

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, soap, soapui

I created a Soap Service mock in SoapUI to run some integration tests. I also put a groovy script to validate some fields within.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
def lineItemId1 = holder["//*:QuotationRequest/*:LineItem[1]/@lineItemId[1]"]
```

When I run my test that call the mock through Eclipse JUnit plugin, and start the SoapUI Mock manually everything goes well, but when I run the test with mvn test  - using soapui-maven-plugin - I got an exception:

```
10:17:55,056 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.saxon.XBeansXPath cannot be cast to 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.SaxonXBeansDelegate$SelectPathInterface], see error log for details
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.saxon.XBeansXPath cannot be cast to 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.SaxonXBeansDelegate$SelectPathInterface


2016-07-14 10:17:55,180  WARN PhaseInterceptorChain:449 - Interceptor for 
{http://www.vertexinc.com/oseries/services/CalculateTax60}CalculateTaxWSService60#{http://www.vertexinc.com/oseries/services/CalculateTax60}calculateTax60 
has thrown exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.
Incoming portion of HTML stream: 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>?</faultcode>
      <faultstring>?</faultstring>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

It seems to be this line that I'm getting error:

```
holder["//*:QuotationRequest/*:LineItem[1]/@lineItemId[1]"]
```

[EDITED]
More info:
snippet of my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Vertex</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>mock</goal>
                    </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <projectFile>${pom.basedir}/../core/Vertex-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <noBlock>true</noBlock>
                        <port>8284</port>
                     </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is the service that I am trying to mock

`http://vha0230.vertexinc.com/vertex-ws/services/CalculateTax60?WSDL`

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like dependency version problem. I do not understand: "When i run through Eclipse JUnit plugin ..., but when I run using soapui-maven-plugin" - these are two completely different frameworks. You should add information how you are running your stuff in one, and then the other. We need steps to reproduce, or it did not happen!

Comment: @SiKing thanks for the feedback. Question edited. Do you think it needed more info here?

Comment: Does the error log have any more information. Post the relevant parts of your pom. I am still just guessing at things, because I still do not see steps to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @SiKing thank you again for the feedback. Let me know it you need more info. ps:. I also tried with the latest version - 5.2.1 -  and I got the same error =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed removing the following dependency

```
                 <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                 <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>5.1.3</version>
                 <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                         <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                         <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                     </dependency>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                         <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                         <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                     </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```